# How to call method of MainWindow from View with Caliburn Micro?

Tags: wpf, binding, caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

I have some Flyouts wich are defined on my MainWindow. I want to open them from a View of my WPF Application.

When I try to bind to my Command i don't get any errors, but the Flyout won't open. When I call the Method directly within the MainWindow, the Flyout opens.

Method on MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public ICommand openFlyoutHomeCommand { get; private set; }
    public void openFlyoutHome()
    {
        FlyoutHomePlayers.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

And the binding in the view, which is shown within the MainWindow:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10 30 10 10" Content="Open Flyout" Command="{Binding openFlyoutHome}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"></Button>
```

Comment: you would be better off using IEventAggregator to send a message to the mainwindow to open the flyout.  This would be handled in the viewmodel of the mainwindow.  reference `IHandle<T>` being inherited on your viewmodel and subscribing to event messages

Comment: If you are using Caliburn.Micro MainWindow should not be in your project. Your main view should be ShellView and your "viewmodel" should be ShellViewModel

Answer (score 0):

First, see your output console to see if there's any binding warning.

Then, you should assign an instance of a Command to your openFlyoutHomeCommand. This instance should reference a delegate which calls your method openFlyoutHome (or create an anonymous delegate which has the same behavior).

In your code sample, your openFlyoutHomeCommand property is null.